# Specific objects flickering when repainted

Tags: java, graphics, awt, flicker

This question is not "*whole screen is flickering*" type of question.

I am trying to understand Java graphics and made a simple game, but when the scene is redrawn with new objects, some objects keeps flickering, **odly** *not the whole screen*.

Here is my `render()` method:

```
private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(6);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        //fill screen with black background
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        //draw cool stuff
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < Element.elements.size(); i++) {
                Element.elements.get(i).render(g2d);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("No such element to render");
        }
        //dispose graphics
        g.dispose();
        g2d.dispose();
        bs.show();
}
```

What can possibly cause this problem? I dont think amount of bubbles cause this problem.

If you want to check out, this is the project zip [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-CSKiNxnQORWG1aYjFrdmFISmc), and 
this is the .jar [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-CSKiNxnQORcmlKa0JHRXhGazQ)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Typically when the screen flickers in an awt/swing application, it is because some one has used SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(), so only part of the page is redrawn during this repaint event, other parts later. Then next step is to check that the canvas is double buffered, after that I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model update, which is being done in the event thread on mouse move, needs to be synchronized with your render thread. The flicker happens because your model is sometimes in an inconsistent state when the render occurs.

One way to fix this is to render in the thread that you're updating your model in. You can run your render in the event thread with `SwingUtilities`:

```
try {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            render();
        }
    });
} catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
    running = false;
    System.err.println("Render interrupted");
}
```

If you're using components that are rendered by AWT or Swing you should *always* do your rendering in the event thread.

As you're controlling the entire rendering process yourself you have the option of rendering in a separate thread, but you will have to synchronize access to your model (that is, writes to the model performed by the event thread should be synchronized with the reads performed by the render thread).

For example:

In `Shredder.scan()` (called from the event thread)

```
public static void scan() {
    synchronized (Element.elements) {
        for (Element element : Element.elements) {
            if (element.containsMouse()) {
                if (element.getSize() < 24) {
                    Element.elements.remove(element);
                } else {
                    element.cloneItself();
                    Element.elements.remove(element);
                }
                skip = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your render thread:

```
synchronized (Element.elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Element.elements.size(); i++) {
        Element.elements.get(i).render(g2d);
    }
}
```

As a matter of form it would be a good idea to put the code that needs to be synchronized in a single location so that calling code doesn't have to be concerned with maintaining consistency.

Comment: This is true for painting components, but is not always a true statement when using a BufferStrategy.